# What type of palm tree is this, including its scientific name?

Tags: identification, palm

[image: Palm tree]

I'm not sure what type of palm tree this is. This is taken in Arizona. I think it is a canary island date palm.

Comment: It looks more like some type of date palm than pindo. Date palms are very common in Arizona. There are a large number of varieties of date palm.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like Phoenix canariensis to me, which is, indeed, commonly known as Canary Island Date Palm, although it doesn't produce dates - the one that does is Phoenix dactylifera. It does produce drupes, the flesh of which is edible, but thin and not worth eating.

http://www.capeoasis.com/garden/html/phoenix_canariensis.html

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that's a sable Palm which has a lot of AKAs such as cabbage Palm.

Sabal palmetto is one scientific name and also like the common name has many taxonomic synonyms.

Comment: The fronds don't look to match Sabal palmetto.